# How can I save in a table the CIs of numerous bootstraps performed by a double loop in R?

Tags: r, nested-loops, correlation, statistics-bootstrap

I have made a double loop in R to make several bootstrap at the same time, but I do not know how to save just the CIs in a table.

I need the double loop to perform Pearson correlation between several variables. I managed to print the CIs of the bootstrap of every corrrelation coefficient in the console window, but I can not save them in a table.

This is the code I have made:

```
library("boot")

data <-       read.csv("D:/TFGregresiones/R/nopvalor_QM.csv",sep =   
','      , header=T)
names <- c("y","si","sa","R","F","Sh","Sim","In","L","Et","Cc")
tabla <- data.frame()
tabla$correlation <- rep( NA, nrow(tabla) )
tabla$LowerCI <- rep( NA, nrow(tabla) )
tabla$UpperCI <- rep( NA, nrow(tabla) )
set.seed(1)
for (i in 4:7){
for(z in 8:11){
cor_boot <- boot(data,
statistic = function(data,j) {
cor(data[j,i], data[j,z], method='pearson')
},
R = 9999
)

IC <- (boot.ci(boot.out=cor_boot,coef=0.95, type = "basic"))
tipo <- (paste(names[i],"~",names[z]))
tabla$LowerCI[tabla==z] <- IC$percent[4]
tabla$UpperCI[tabla==z] <- IC$percent[5]
tabla$correlation[tabla==z] <- tipo

}
}
```

Thanks you in advance.

dput():

```
structure(list(year = c(2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L), site = c("M", "Q", 
"M", "M", "M", "Q", "M", "Q", "M", "M", "M", "M", "Q", "M", "Q", 
"M", "Q", "M", "Q", "M", "Q", "Q", "Q", "M", "M", "M", "Q", "M", 
"Q", "M", "Q", "Q", "Q", "M", "Q", "M", "M", "Q", "Q", "Q", "M", 
"Q", "Q", "M", "M", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "M", 
"Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", 
"Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q"), sample = 
c("MdBCT2PF3_44375", 
"QdAT66PF2_44374", "MdBT3PF3_44375", "MdBT1PF2_44375", 
"MdBT4PF3_44375", 
"QdAT66PF1_44374", "MdAT4PF2_44375", "QdCPF11_44374", 
"MdACT3PF2_44375", 
"MdAT2PF3_44375", "MdACT1PF2_44375", "MdBT4PF1_44375", 
"QdAPF8_44374", 
"MdAT1PF1_44375", "QdCPF3_44374", "MdBCT2PF2_44375", 
"QdBPF2_44374", 
"MdBCT1PF1_44375", "QdBPF5_44374", "MdAT2PF1_44375", 
"QdAPF1_44374", 
"QdBPF10_44374", "QdAPF7_44374", "MdBT4PF2_44375", 
"MdACT3PF3_44375", 
"MdBCT4PF2_44375", "QdCPF7_44374", "MdBT2PF1_44375", 
"QdAPF5_44374", 
"MdBT1PF3_44375", "QdCPF9_44374", "QdAPF3_44374", "QdAPF6_44374", 
"MdBT3PF2_44375", "QdBT14PF3_44374", "MdBCT3PF2_44375", 
"MdBCT3PF3_44375", 
"QdCPF1_44374", "QdAPF11_44374", "QdAPF2_44374", "MdBT1PF1_44375", 
"QdAT66PF3_44374", "QdAPF12_44374", "MdBT3PF1_44375", 
"MdBT2PF2_44375", 
"QdCPF12_44374", "QdAT16PF3_44374", "QdBPF3_44374", 
"QdBPF9_44374", 
"QdBT14PF1_44374", "QdBPF4_44374", "QdAPF9_44374", 
"QdBPF12_44374", 
"MdBCT4PF1_44375", "QdBPF11_44374", "QdAPF4_44374", 
"QdBPF1_44374", 
"QdAPF10_44374", "QdCPF6_44374", "QdCT6PF1_44374", 
"QdCPF10_44374", 
"QdCPF4_44374", "QdBT12PF1_44374", "QdBT12PF3_44374", 
"QdAT16PF1_44374", 
"QdBT12PF2_44374", "QdBPF7_44374", "QdBPF6_44374", "QdCPF2_44374", 
"QdAT16PF2_44374", "QdCPF8_44374", "QdCT8PF2_44374", 
"QdCPF5_44374", 
"QdBT14PF2_44374", "QdBPF8_44374"), Riqueza = c(7L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 
8L, 10L, 6L, 11L, 9L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 
8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 
11L, 8L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 9L, 14L, 9L, 10L, 
5L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 7L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 
10L, 8L, 12L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 6L), 
Fisher = c(1.708985, 1.891572, 1.505205, 2.19422, 2.244685, 
2.185502, 1.571136, 3.492045, 2.191208, 1.566767, 2.283096, 
2.766299, 1.967769, 2.026361, 2.450491, 2.268592, 2.450491, 
1.969292, 2.34142, 1.916541, 1.521371, 2.096483, 1.815406, 
2.629094, 2.875309, 1.502607, 2.013007, 1.373573, 1.294698, 
2.512279, 2.241081, 1.405551, 2.670416, 2.994008, 2.13827, 
2.600857, 1.267197, 1.478948, 1.641599, 1.405551, 2.032919, 
2.590653, 2.060482, 1.668902, 2.05111, 3.750578, 2.207323, 
2.672846, 1.156875, 2.590653, 3.453925, 2.794345, 2.207323, 
3.300504, 2.639606, 1.650668, 1.550761, 2.321796, 2.526427, 
2.797725, 3.130264, 3.843368, 2.756203, 1.726265, 3.134622, 
2.298767, 2.600857, 2.039589, 1.389048, 2.916805, 2.891003, 
2.681496, 3.511837, 2.53803, 1.556061), Shannon = c(1.339391, 
1.5702279, 1.0642722, 1.3340137, 1.0985794, 1.2743088, 1.0324565, 
1.6677331, 0.94736, 0.7322081, 0.8028045, 1.5389554, 0.9842245, 
1.1596322, 1.4201613, 1.0881245, 1.3145337, 0.7212671, 1.3068037, 
1.3638757, 1.065592, 1.4373841, 0.8130178, 1.3621294, 1.2735538, 
1.0868267, 1.2629897, 1.0173147, 0.6547677, 1.353537, 1.1852305, 
0.5610835, 0.9416518, 1.4760705, 1.4996377, 1.5416501, 0.9249011, 
1.1756805, 0.9416905, 0.5871208, 1.4278653, 1.7011227, 0.9638479, 
1.1050305, 1.0145463, 1.4225003, 1.3767472, 1.5058417, 1.0240323, 
1.767559, 1.5511679, 1.0576901, 1.3183305, 1.738367, 1.2027619, 
0.7283449, 1.1885018, 1.0651473, 1.4870934, 1.9257449, 1.5537501, 
1.3413622, 1.614922, 1.6244515, 1.8244888, 1.4994996, 1.143603, 
1.3641613, 1.434386, 1.7448453, 1.4869944, 1.4583592, 1.880055, 
1.8130411, 1.1600477), Simpson = c(0.3251642, 0.2478027, 
0.4354043, 0.3429485, 0.5263957, 0.4238095, 0.4653061, 0.2800789, 
0.5958277, 0.6944856, 0.6529012, 0.3188, 0.4685412, 0.4014516, 
0.3207334, 0.5102788, 0.3587596, 0.7124224, 0.3513968, 0.3429784, 
0.4018667, 0.3185596, 0.6476757, 0.3685076, 0.3818881, 0.4351901, 
0.3816885, 0.5049349, 0.7042011, 0.3435491, 0.4075521, 0.7602285, 
0.6088889, 0.313724, 0.3019112, 0.3362051, 0.5609565, 0.3781179, 
0.4538562, 0.7441077, 0.3208381, 0.2321292, 0.4541402, 0.4069523, 
0.4762317, 0.348114, 0.3284912, 0.2828099, 0.4994592, 0.2071331, 
0.29625, 0.4806882, 0.3597412, 0.2487574, 0.4125885, 0.6756206, 
0.3837755, 0.4519031, 0.3055054, 0.1703688, 0.2877739, 0.4392361, 
0.2569356, 0.2405733, 0.2025552, 0.2970475, 0.467128, 0.3273209, 
0.2879631, 0.2305456, 0.3165004, 0.3645316, 0.1937932, 0.2217867, 
0.4182099), Intercepto = c(12.5313895, 11.30591711, 14.0944488, 
13.01033902, 12.14107914, 14.59087595, 15.04634049, 12.11264417, 
10.06303398, 12.24309966, 15.04828716, 11.79067112, 13.02928066, 
16.74570204, 13.6459301, 9.434868041, 12.88588815, 9.933156666, 
13.01564518, 14.32243505, 13.28438222, 14.5553486, 14.03812412, 
20.29993579, 18.81787521, 16.09897661, 10.92444427, 17.53979184, 
15.10200814, 12.90097341, 12.01353519, 13.46010099, 14.01625107, 
13.98397573, 15.84959519, 10.96842696, 16.45702332, 13.3118117, 
16.33732654, 11.07604397, 16.45329433, 9.564071074, 15.01880714, 
16.08587807, 17.21201844, 14.76953087, 14.45721297, 12.64913135, 
14.66536531, 14.15599562, 15.51031611, 15.08261239, 14.85261576, 
16.89388977, 13.64988942, 16.69683654, 15.6679898, 14.41383675, 
14.07129159, 12.46399427, 13.9243076, 15.327903, 14.87200928, 
17.0843279, 13.93072584, 12.67960824, 13.21027641, 13.30828031, 
17.00194303, 14.33377857, 12.50478397, 12.0669364, 15.16762284, 
16.85240474, 17.61549093), Lambda = c(1.143635802, 1.209458131, 
0.975111105, 1.146402531, 1.028314634, 0.939151967, 0.897970591, 
1.185346874, 1.271352489, 0.994250289, 0.893770823, 1.147404461, 
1.150130452, 0.73390873, 0.991498027, 1.340567134, 1.071544479, 
1.304021074, 1.061068528, 0.843330484, 1.114460908, 0.912296391, 
1.070581212, 0.381375232, 0.604232724, 0.812483158, 1.352983828, 
0.547936885, 0.950576891, 1.082962273, 1.251412904, 1.211393995, 
1.005884692, 1.084796385, 0.762469245, 1.172462095, 0.660650204, 
1.011987334, 0.950217272, 1.374921861, 0.745007917, 1.368711407, 
0.947958162, 0.837547429, 0.655306808, 0.947153111, 0.898211528, 
1.130500047, 0.901282675, 0.91824414, 0.804982922, 0.852175835, 
0.841685442, 0.713987368, 1.138639669, 0.759860183, 0.798711258, 
0.957504125, 1.032680083, 1.044676978, 0.928422262, 0.793338145, 
0.83528088, 0.718988823, 0.978772222, 1.096933411, 1.142297897, 
1.029576117, 0.692313064, 0.899183177, 1.129576591, 1.108063743, 
0.805362277, 0.719007145, 0.578590743), ET = c(16.32030971, 
12.0526831, 35.46318928, 16.11368754, 27.75688538, 41.85005817, 
50.58931722, 13.46809751, 9.063480861, 32.471281, 51.57727035, 
16.03950931, 15.83941348, 107.6917762, 32.88546188, 6.589701342, 
22.74631463, 7.797544322, 23.87057849, 65.06374123, 18.66715717, 
47.35951192, 22.8474416, 546.0715316, 195.6746438, 74.99523736, 
6.223466326, 253.5865586, 39.70509304, 21.58119327, 9.935144591, 
11.94571117, 30.77730696, 21.39967758, 94.4194595, 14.29143407, 
150.903597, 29.92439178, 39.77090339, 5.625437164, 102.3255685, 
5.788648593, 40.18682318, 66.81979548, 154.6629836, 40.3360882, 
50.53321668, 17.33803622, 49.82354789, 46.07992038, 77.63081686, 
62.4666664, 65.55851627, 118.03893, 16.70016115, 95.56076857, 
79.90564914, 38.45844763, 27.20444273, 25.74222275, 43.96989981, 
81.90750745, 67.52090273, 115.351263, 34.87028974, 20.2363964, 
16.42117412, 27.59610356, 130.4289121, 50.30760543, 17.41192621, 
19.22527293, 77.49531466, 115.3415305, 220.2006081), CC = 
c(1197221.995, 
74406.81277, 2850975.81, 8804672.932, 464538.6026, 2467745.257, 
3602266.765, 777131.1692, 731580.1866, 1483151.244, 2141815.054, 
914383.4647, 1377759.44, 1501939.775, 286955.6919, 1699388.958, 
118050.1369, 2094674.577, 427597.5293, 1792866.192, 1612788.053, 
660475.5419, 1506336.243, 14165103.4, 19338763.33, 4878612.62, 
516268.7184, 3610155.679, 2041521.804, 1122221.091, 705187.3411, 
2016478.844, 116343.2985, 4894581.737, 1108406.348, 211645.2395, 
3557356.773, 1762428.98, 3326408.495, 374842.3255, 3828961.331, 
226592.3643, 697331.3971, 2683737.85, 2368841.611, 1299307.2, 
810153.5992, 1499437.282, 1541866.725, 325830.5708, 166069.8931, 
324650.6796, 571235.5456, 5494829.877, 618722.6778, 2090596.777, 
2260055.871, 219211.1975, 2219227.392, 413319.4237, 950384.9881, 
1695995.268, 351375.7946, 660380.6706, 298575.5178, 191282.9143, 
844588.8338, 716505.3724, 3073746.166, 352728.0352, 502234.6238, 
334632.2173, 150808.8515, 1190793.755, 2709346.836)), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-75L))
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Twitter Bootstrap?

Comment: We don't have access to your D drive.  Please provide some test data using `dput()`.

Comment: @Limey Ok, I have already done it.